# Why did Philip the evangelist have a house?

Tags: textual-discrepancies, disciple

Philip the evangelist was a disciple according to Acts 6:2-5

> 2 Then **the twelve called the multitude of the disciples unto them, and said**, It is not reason that we should leave the word of God, and serve tables.
>   3 Wherefore, brethren, look ye out among you **seven** men of honest report, full of the Holy Ghost and wisdom, whom we may appoint over this business.
>   4 But we will give ourselves continually to prayer, and to the ministry of the word.
>   5 And the saying pleased the whole multitude: and they chose Stephen, a man full of faith and of the Holy Ghost, and **Philip**, and Prochorus, and Nicanor, and Timon, and Parmenas, and Nicolas a proselyte of Antioch:

Jesus said you can't be a disciple unless you forsake everything in Luke 14:33

> So likewise, whosoever **he be of you that forsaketh not all that he hath, he cannot be my disciple.**

But Philip didn't forsake everything because he still had a house according to Acts 21:8

> And the next day we that were of Paul's company departed, and came unto Caesarea: and **we entered into the house of Philip the evangelist, which was one of the seven; and abode with him.**

So how could Philip be a disciple and not forsake his house at the same time?

Comment: I think St. Peter had a house too, its a good bet that's where his family lived, at least his mother-in-law...

Answer (score 5):

Consider the [Amplified version of Luke 14:33](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2014%3A33&version=AMP):

> So then, any of you who does not forsake (renounce, **surrender claim to**, give up, say good-bye to) all that he has cannot be My disciple.

In other words, selling everything is not required of those who want to follow Christ (with [one noteable exception](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+18%3A22)) but rather a willingness to accept that [everything belongs to God](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians+10:26), [everything we have is a gift from God](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+1%3A16&version=AMP) and therefore [we should be willing to give up anything, if required](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians+3%3A7-8).

Incidentally, Philip is hardly the only believing home owner. Other examples are [Simon Peter](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+4:38), [Simon the Leper](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+14:3), [Martha](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+10:38), [Lydia](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+16:40), [Titus Justus](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+18:7), [Prisca and Aquila](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+16%3A3-5) (also [here](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians+16:19)), [Nympha](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Colossians+4:15) and [Philemon](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philemon+1%3A1-2) to give a few Biblical examples.

Comment: If anyone can suggest better verse examples for my second paragraph, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Ok so luke 14:33 really means you must be willing to forsake everything, not literally forsake everything. Those people you mentioned did own homes but were they all disciples?

Comment: @Jake: of those I mentioned, only Simon Peter was a disciple.

Comment: @Wikis, only Simon Peter was an Apostle. The others all seem to be disciples (follower, student, believer in Christ). Philip was set apart in the special role of deacon or minister, and was not an apostle either, but was a disciple as well, just as all the twelve apostles were.

Comment: @disciple: strictly speaking, you are correct. I was trying to answer in what I thought was the spirit of the question ie "original twelve" but your remark is well made. Thank you.